# How do I transition animation before React rerenders?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I have a custom checkbox like so:
https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-resonance-09dii

Based on this codepen: https://codepen.io/Sambego/pen/yiruz

```css
input:checked:before {
  transition: transform 2s cubic-bezier(0.45, 1.8, 0.5, 0.75);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0, 0);
}
```

My 'checking' animation works fine, but I would like to also animate unchecking. I believe react is rerendering my input before my css transition can occur. How can I add an animation to uncheck too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'unchecking' animation works fine as well, the problem is that your background-color goes back to white immediately so your white check mark will be invisible.

I would probably add a transition period to the background or change the color of the check mark to blue on its way out.
Maybe like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/x5mbi